# AWS Lambda : creating the trigger

Tags: aws-lambda

When I try to add the trigger, I get the following error:

"There was an error creating the trigger: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type."

I'm not sure what's gone wrong here.

Comment: Did you created a trigger with the same name earlier and used it somewhere and then delete that trigger, and now creating trigger with the same name? This kind of problem happens when the previously created trigger is still "linked". Also you can check the AWS forms [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=670712)

Comment: Please tell us more about what you were doing. What type of trigger? What values did you select? Do you have any other Lambda functions with triggers defined?

Comment: One reason could be that some other lambda function previously using the same trigger was deleted. What is the trigger you are using to invoke Lambda?

Answer (score 6):

One reason could be that some other lambda function previously using the same trigger was deleted. This does not automatically clear the event notification from the S3 side. You have to navigate to the S3 console and manually delete the stale event notifications. Once that is done, you should be able to create the same trigger again for another lambda function.

Answer (score 4):

1. Navigate to S3 and click on the name of your bucket.
2. Click on the “Properties” tab.
3. Scroll down to the Advanced properties and on the events section you should see 1 or more active notifications.
4. Click on the square to edit notifications and delete the notification that is still listening to your lambda function in error.

Congrats, no more dangling reference!