# Unknown Error: API response: unable to validate the following destination configurations in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Earlier I used to create triggers by proving below info from AWS S3 UI:
Under 'S3 Bucket properties':
Event name, Prefix, Suffix, All object create events, Lambda function, Enter Lambda function ARN  >> Save changes.

Right it is giving below error:
Unknown Error:
**API response: unable to validate the following destination configurations in s3**

So how can I create a trigger by using command line parameters ?? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/aws-sdk-s3/1.8.2/Aws/S3/Types/LambdaFunctionConfiguration
I found this link useful, but how can i run this ?

Comment: Can you provide the full error?

Comment: I'm able to see only above highlighted error.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215544/s3-bucket-lambda-event-unable-to-validate-the-following-destination-configurati