# How to invoke a lambda function upon file receive in an existing S3 bucket after 'Unable to validate the following destination configurations'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am attempting to create an event notification when a file is created within a bucket that has a specific prefix via an S3 trigger within the Lambda GUI in the AWS Management Console. I successfully did this without any errors over a month ago for 6 different functions. Unfortunately, after trying to create new functions, I am receiving the:

"Unable to validate the following destination configurations" error.

I tried several online tutorials and videos and still no luck. This has been an ongoing problem for over a month. I've tried invoking via Lambda, SNS, and more while trying to create several variations of JSON format policies. Below are some of the resources I've tried to utilize so far:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-event-notifications.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjSW75YsBMM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2Ra7X8rymw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKBeg-K2vdc&t=177s

[S3 Bucket Lambda Event: Unable to validate the following destination configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215544/s3-bucket-lambda-event-unable-to-validate-the-following-destination-configurati#comment88629184_47674337)

What I am very unclear about is how the other 6 functions are working with identical permissions, but I am unable to create other ones. Configuration (with the exception of the Triggers) are identical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!